AWS Security Lake Delegate Administrator and Terraform
Reading through these docs it calls out that the Org Master account needs to define the delegate administrator account, but looking at these resources in the terraform provider, I don't see how you would declare your delegate administrator account? Using terraform, how would you declare a delegate administrator account with the given arguments available here?
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/securitylake_data_lake

There is a resource for what you need:
resource "aws_organizations_delegated_administrator" "security_lake" {
  account_id        = <some AWS account ID>
  service_principal = "securitylake.amazonaws.com"
}

There is also this document from AWS with more details.
